# Can I have an icon on my desktop housing multiple folders?

Tags: icons, directory

I'm trying to clean up my desktop. So far I have a few folders for class notes, mounted files (iso) a shared folder for the network, etc.

I'd like to be able to have an icon on my desktop that i could rollover, and have a display show up listing the folders located in it. Something to just organize my desktop icons into categories.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the Screenlet [FolderView](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=102890). It will not give you the roll-over effect, but can help you categories elements on desktop.

To install Screenlets, run the following in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

The FolderView screenlet will show you the content of a folder in a "fence" -- hence, for each Folderview, you have to have the stuff you want shown in it in a separate folder (located just somewhere, not necessarily on your desktop). If you want to "clean up", you can just close a given Folderview.

[image: Screenlets Manager, the FolderView settings where the portrayed folder is chosen and the screenlet it self on the right]
Here you see the main Screenlets Manager, the FolderView settings where the portrayed folder is chosen and the screenlet it self on the right. There are a lot of customization options with respect to the look of each FolderView screenlet.